# Will Ubuntu Phone support MSExchange?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ms-exchange

Will Ubuntu Phone support MSExchange mail and calendar?

Comment: The current official answer would be, that it currently does not since there seems to be a calendar but no mail app among the core apps. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/CoreApps